# How to explan my GML model in the method section?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

First I am an absolute beginner in this field. For my research task, I use the poisson-GLM, quasi-poisson GLM, and Binomial GLM. I have finished my job of reporting result, but i am not good at explaining my model for the method section. Can anybody provided some paper conerning this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always set out the formulation in the three stages

1. (stochastic component) $Y_i \sim Pois(\lambda_i)$
2. (link function) $\log(\lambda_i) = \eta_i$
3. (linear predictor) $\eta_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i$

And give a reference to Nelder and Wedderburn 1974 or Nelder and McCullough.   Then you can change the stochastic component or linear predictor as you need and keep the explanation fairly terse.